# Does renameTo in java preserves old folder in case of error?

Tags: java, apache, file, directory, rename

I need to rename:

```
newfolder -> oldfolder;
```

I need to be sure that in case of exception old folder will be saved.

So I think to do next:

```
 1. rename oldfolder -> tempfolder.
 2. rename newfolder -> oldfolder.
 3. If previous ok - delete oldfolder.
```

But I have dubious - may be Apache FileUtils do the same. Or operation of renaming is safe.
What is correct?
Thanks.

Comment: You're asking if FileUtils deletes a folder if a rename fails?

Comment: in source it ask system to do it, so I am not sure...

Comment: What have you tried? This seems like a very simple thing to test on whatever target platform you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to rename a folder to an existing name it will fail. So if you want to replace a folder you should go with the alternative approach you already mentioned.

The logic would be

1. folder to folder.bak
2. folder.new to folder
3. if successful, delete folder.bak
4. elsewise folder.bak to folder and raise error

Comment: I think not only. Also possible access, os error, locked or not (e.g. some file inside is open) etc.

Comment: but question is - what will be wil oldfolder - in case of faliure I need save old data

Comment: if you want to "retract` your answer you should delete it. If you can't delete it `flag` it and ask a moderator to delete it for you. I rolled it back so other people can see what you actually said.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is dependent on the file system that you are utilizing.  Looking at the source code, File.io.renameto() is platform dependent that delegates to a native O/S call. As far as I am aware, all of the O/S renames are considered safe.  It does the 'delete' (usually just removing the INODE pointer) after the new INODE/pointer has been updated for the new destination.  While you cannot assume the renameTo() will succeed (always check the return code), you can reliably assume that if it fails, then the original directory should be intact.